# Why is my count that is being returned a wrong value?

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

```
    public static int countNeighbors(boolean[][] BB, int r, int c) {
    int countalive = 0;
    for (int i = r -1;i<=r+1; i++) {
        for (int j = c -1; j<c+1;j++) {

            if (BB[i][j]) {
                countalive++;

            }

        }
    }
    return countalive;
}
```

Matrix being read.

```
oooooooo
o###oooo
o####o#o
ooo##o#o
o#o#o##o
oooooooo
```

I noticed something wrong so I printed out this portion of the code. When ran with specifications

```
countNeighbors(myNewMatrix,1,1)
```

I get the returned value of 2, when it should in face be 3.

It is counting the number of tiles that are True(#) around it.

This is for a "game of life" assignment.

Comment: Are you sure the BB array contains the flags that reflect that matrix?

Comment: @Eran Yes, I just found that I needed it to be j<=C+1, but then when I changed it now I have one more number than I am supposed to.

Comment: you need to check your boundary conditions.  when row is 0 or 7 and when column is 0 or 5 you will get an exception.

Comment: @DwB I have a seperate method that will do the actual selection of where it starts and ends. 

`for (int i = 1; i < NB.length - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < NB[i].length - 1; j++) {
  int count = countNeighbors(OB,i,j);
  if (count>BL && count < BH){
   System.out.print("-");
     
     
  } if(count<DL && count >DH){
   System.out.print("#");`

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 neighbors of (1,1) at (1,2), (2,1), and (2,2).  Your code is wrong on 2 accounts:

1. You are counting the cell itself (1,1).  This makes the count 1 too high.  Introduce an `if` to avoid counting the (r,c) location itself.
2. You are stopping too early in the `j` `for` loop, before it gets to `c + 1`.  This makes the count 2 too low (missing 2 matches).  Change the condition to `j<=c+1`, to be consistent with the `i` `for` loop condition.

The combined effects of the two errors (+1 and -2) explain why your count is low by `1`.

Comment: I added a if (BB[i][j] == BB[r][c]){continue; } but it just didn't count anything

Comment: I would use code such as `if (i == r && j == c) { continue; }`.